# How to find the duration of Flight in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I am beginner to Neo4j, How to calculate the duration of the flight from A1 to A3.
I am confused on doing the subtraction operation on the arrival and departure flights. I want to calculate the total time from A1 to A3 Airports. Here my Console http://console.neo4j.org/?id=g0mv8x

Really Appreciate for your cooperation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one is a bit tricky.  First the query, then the explanation:

```
MATCH p=shortestPath((a1:AIRPORT { name: "Airport A1" })-[*]-(a3:AIRPORT { name: "Airport A3" }))
RETURN reduce(totalDuration=0, duration IN 
           extract(leg IN relationships(p)| leg.duration) | 
               totalDuration + toInt(duration));
```

So first, you need to find the shortest path between the two.  That's the first line.  There are many paths, in general you want the cheapest/shortest.

Second, you then have a path.  So the first thing you need to do is get all of the "durations" out of the relationships.  That's what `extract(leg IN relationships(p)| leg.duration)` does.  Extract pulls something out of a collection.   Finally, you need to sum them.  That's what `reduce` does.  Notice that your durations are strings (they should be numerics) so you have to use `toInt()` in order to convert it to a number that you can sum up.

Answer (score 3):

This is indeed tricky, since you should not even be using the `duration` property to do the calculation!

That is because multi-leg flights always have some lag time between the flights, which you need to consider when you calculate the total duration. Therefore, you need to subtract the arrival time of the last leg from the departure time of the first leg.

Judging from your sample data timestamps and duration values, it looks like your timestamps are in units of hours times 100. Caveat: the calculation is only possible if the timestamps incorporate date information, since the flight legs can span multiple days.

## Getting all practical itineraries

Here is how you can get all the practical flights from A1 to A3, along with the names of the start/end airports and the flightcodes for each leg:

```
MATCH (a:AIRPORT { name:"Airport A1" })-[c:Connect*]->(b:AIRPORT { name:"Airport A3" })
WHERE ALL(i IN RANGE(0, LENGTH(c)-2) WHERE (c[i+1]).dptrTime - (c[i]).arrvTime > 33)
RETURN a.name AS from, b.name AS to,
  EXTRACT(x IN c | x.flightcode) AS flights,
  (LAST(c).arrvTime - HEAD(c).dptrTime)/100.0 AS duration;
```

To ensure valid and practical itineraries, the `WHERE` clause filters out itineraries that do not allow at least 20 minutes (33% of an hour) between each leg.

[Here is a console](http://console.neo4j.org/?id=r22ryw) that show these results:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| FROM         | to           | flights          | duration |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| "Airport A1" | "Airport A3" | ["F2","F4"]      | 4.0      |
| "Airport A1" | "Airport A3" | ["F1","F3"]      | 5.0      |
| "Airport A1" | "Airport A3" | ["F5","F6","F7"] | 216.0    |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Note: The `216.0` hour duration comes from the arrival time of `23000` in your original sample data. This was probably a typo, but I left it unchanged.

## Getting the fastest practical itinerary

You can modify the above query to get the fastest itinerary:

```
MATCH (a:AIRPORT { name:"Airport A1" })-[c:Connect*]->(b:AIRPORT { name:"Airport A3" })
WHERE ALL(i IN RANGE(0, LENGTH(c)-2) WHERE (c[i+1]).dptrTime - (c[i]).arrvTime > 33)
RETURN a.name AS FROM , b.name AS to, EXTRACT(x IN c | x.flightcode) AS flights,(LAST(c).arrvTime-HEAD(c).dptrTime)/100.0 AS duration
ORDER BY duration
LIMIT 1;
```

Results:

```
+------------------------------------------------------+
| FROM         | to           | flights     | duration |
+------------------------------------------------------+
| "Airport A1" | "Airport A3" | ["F2","F4"] | 4.0      |
+------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks alot, yes 23000 is Spelling error, I will correct it to 2300.

Comment: [tag:cybersam] what if I want only to calculate the duration flight for only feasible flights according to their arrival and departure time from A1 to A3.

Comment: `//Query:
MATCH path =((A0:AIRPORT)-[Connections:Connect*]->(A2:AIRPORT))
WHERE A0.name='Airport A1' AND A2.name='Airport A3' AND ALL (i IN Range(0, length(Connections)-2) 
                                                             WHERE ((Connections[i]).arrvTime <(Connections[i+1]).dptrTime))
RETURN DISTINCT extract(Connect IN Connections | Connect.flightcode)`

Comment: Thanks. I have updated my answer to incorporate the validation test.

Comment: I have also modified the `WHERE` clause to test that there is at least 20 minutes between each leg, since shorter intervals are not practical. You can adjust the `33` (which stands for 33% of an hour) to whatever interval makes sense.

Comment: [tag:cybersam] It's really very clear algorithm, and your cooperation is highly appreciated!